# Javascript's Map() function's weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, scala

I was stumbling on http://lihaoyi.github.io/hands-on-scala-js/  where I found below :

```
javascript> ["10", "10", "10", "10"].map(parseInt)
[10, NaN, 2, 3] // WTF


scala> List("10", "10", "10", "10").map(parseInt)
List(10, 10, 10, 10) // Yay!
```

Below are details of map() from : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm

> Javascript array map() method creates a new array with the results of
>   calling a provided function on every element in this array.

No explanation given on former link mentioned. 
Couldn't understand whats going on with 2nd param? Why is parseInt returning NaN?

Comment: Notice, that you're passing an index as  `radix` parameter in `parseInt`.

Comment: I agree. The actual proper code is `["10", "10", "10", "10"].map(function(bla) { return parseInt(bla,10)})` - the code in the Scala example is BS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` accepts 2 parameters, 1st - string, 2nd- radix. Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

`map` passing 3 parameters to callback, value, key and whole arry. Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

So you're seeing execution of code like this

```
parseInt("10", 0);
parseInt("10", 1);
parseInt("10", 2);
parseInt("10", 3);
```

and it works correctly :)

To fix, you can do something like:

```
["10", "10", "10", "10"].map(function (value) {
    return parseInt(value);
});
//[10, 10, 10, 10]
```